# Request to Kerberos authenticated API considered unauthorized despite having kerberos ticket in authorization header

Tags: apache, flask, kerberos

I am trying to call a Flask API endpoint (http://monarch.example.com:8080/) hosted in Apache web server in a Linux machine. This endpoint is protected by Kerberos authentication. I use `kinit user` to initialize Kerberos. Then I am using python kerberos library to get the ticket and requests library for the api call. I am providing the ticket in the Authorization header of the request. Relevant code snippet for that:

```
`__, krb_context = kerberos.authGSSClientInit("HTTP@monarch.example.com")
kerberos.authGSSClientStep(krb_context, "")
auth_header = ("Negotiate " + kerberos.authGSSClientResponse(krb_context))
headers = {"Authorization": auth_header}`
```

I have checked that the Authorization header is populated with a value.
However I get 401-unauthorized as response.

The Kerberos configuration from `/etc/apache2/sites-available/monarch.conf` for the Service containing the endpoint  is:

```
<Directory /var/www/monarch>
       AuthType Kerberos
       AuthName "Acme Corporation"
       KrbAuthRealms EXAMPLE.COM
       KrbMethodNegotiate Off
       KrbSaveCredentials Off
       KrbVerifyKDC Off
       KrbMethodK5Passwd On
       # Krb5Keytab /etc/apache2/http.keytab
       Krb5keytab /etc/krb5.keytab
       Require user user@EXAMPLE.COM
</Directory>
```

Lastly, the list of principals is:

```
host/monarch.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
HTTP/monarch.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
K/M@EXAMPLE.COM
kadmin/admin@EXAMPLE.COM
kadmin/changepw@EXAMPLE.COM
krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM
user@EXAMPLE.COM
root/admin@EXAMPLE.COM
```

And the list of keys from `/etc/krb5.keytab` is:

```
slot KVNO Principal
---- ---- ---------------------------------------------------------------------
   1    2     host/monarch.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   2    2     host/monarch.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   3    2     HTTP/monarch.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
   4    2     HTTP/monarch.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM
```

I have been stuck with this problem for a few days now. It would be great if anyone can help me in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to send a 'Negotiate' auth token but you've *disabled* the actual method – that's what `KrbMethodNegotiate Off` did.

The only thing you've left enabled is "kpasswd", i.e. HTTP Basic auth where the server merely validates the password against a Kerberos KDC. (And on top of that, you even disabled KrbVerifyKDC, the lack of which makes the password-check subject to trivial KDC spoofing attacks.)

Do not add unnecessary options; all you need is `Krb5Keytab`.

Although in 2023 you probably should not use mod_auth_kerb in general. You should be using [mod_auth_gssapi](https://github.com/gssapi/mod_auth_gssapi).

---

Similarly, use  [pyspnego](https://pypi.org/project/pyspnego/) or [python-gssapi](https://pypi.org/project/gssapi/) instead of python-kerberos; they still use the same libgssapi underneath, but they have a more pleasant Python API. (And maybe do not use those directly, either – use [requests-kerberos](https://pypi.org/project/requests-kerberos/) or [requests-gssapi](https://pypi.org/project/requests-gssapi/) or [urllib-gssapi](https://pypi.org/project/urllib-gssapi/) or [httpx-gssapi](https://github.com/pythongssapi/httpx-gssapi).)

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. I updated the configuration file following your suggestion. However now I am getting status code 500. And the related error.log entries are:

[Sun Oct 08 21:38:09.888197 2023] [auth_kerb:error] [pid 5353:tid 140284828677696] [client 192.168.0.181:50580] failed to verify krb5 credentials: Service key not available
[client 192.168.0.181:52252] gss_acquire_cred() failed: No credentials were supplied, or the credentials were unavailab

Could you kindly help with this? Currently KDC and Apache server are in the same machine and both are using same keytab file.

Comment: Both messages indicate that the keytab file wasn't accessible. Is the file readable by the httpd user (www-data or similar)? Generally Apache should have its keytab as a **separate** file from the general machine keytab, precisely because of file permissions.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. The keytab was not accessible to www-data. Once I fixed that, I got correct response. Thank you again for your time and help. It was a life saver.